# Получить список объектов со свойствами из другого списка

Tags: c#, linq

Есть класс:

```
public class Info
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

С помощью `LINQ` можно получить список идентификаторов:

```
List<Info> info;
List<int> ids = info.Select(x => x.id).ToList();
```

Возможно ли с помощью `LINQ` создать новый список `List<Info>`, состоящий из объектов `Info`, свойство `id` которых берется из списка `List<int> ids`, а свойство `Name` для всех элементов будет одинаковым?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте

Для получения из *info*

`var newList = info.Select(x => new Info(){Id = x.id, Name = "sample"}).ToList();`

Для получения из *ids*

`var newList = ids.Select(x => new Info(){Id = x, Name = "sample"}).ToList();`

Comment: Исправьте `x.id` на `x`

Comment: @AGS17 Это бы понадобилось, если бы я брал данные из ```ids```, а не  ```info```

Comment: @AGS17 зачем? В `х` храниться объект типа `Info`, а не `int`

Comment: Сорян, я подумал что нужно из списка айдишников сгенерить.

Comment: @AGS17 да, по идее надо было из них, я просто решил показать как получить результат сразу, не создавая промежуточные списки.

Comment: @AGS17, все верно, по ним и нужно

Comment: @tym32167, изначально нет списка `List<Info> info`, его нужно получить из айдишников. Сделал так: `var newList = ids.Select(x => new Info(){Id = x, Name = "sample"}).ToList();`

Comment: @Sv__t Ок, дополнил ответ

Comment: Да, я видел. Разобрался. Всем спасибо!